# My fast.ai install wasn't working in Windows 7. Hope things are fixed these days

Tags: python, deep-learning, anaconda, fast-ai

[from 2018] I created a new Windows 7 admin account for development so there's no spaces in directory names. I installed Anaconda for Windows and ran a git copy for fast.ai. I ran a conda activate environment for the CPU version of fast.ai, and at this point there are no errors.

But then I try to run pytests and it chokes with a hint to use packages/modules valid Python names pointing to the __ init___.py file in the tests directory complaining about "import cv2,torch" and then another __ init__.py showing "from torch ._C import *" ImportError: DLL load failed. The specified module cannot be found.

[Edit: 4 years later trying to undo my poor posting]

I don't remember that post, but I do try to promote fast.ai as the algorithm of AI algorithms that they are. It's a free class offered online that you can rent GPU time from 3rd-parties if you don't have your own system.

One time I built an Alienware laptop with the best of the best for NVIDIA AI that Dell let me cancel. I did my best to let them know that it was better than a gaming system designed for deep learning based on the research I'd been doing at the time.

Just wish I had the resources to focus on it knowing how important deep learning is for the BRAIN Initiative since Heaven isn't going to just build itself (Matthew 20). As the Acoustic Kiddy of Acoustic Kitties for cyborg studies, I'm focused on letting folks know my old paper in 2005 was credited as the basis for the Wikipedia article about brain implants after I'd been ordered to stand down about it in 1997 by the Department of Defense, and denied by the University of Washington in 1988 wanting to study the EEG brain-to-brain interface they'd finally publish in 2013.

I suppose my most urgent question regarding AI development online is, do they have an emergency shutdown phone number?, since you're being charged by the minute and computers go offline for various reasons.

Comment: I don't remember that post from 4 years ago, but I do try to promote fast.ai as the algorithm of AI algorithms that they are. Just wish I had the resources to focus on it knowing how important deep learning is for the BRAIN Initiative.

Comment: During the Seattle grunge days of ```UNIX``` spreading word of Quack to security guards finding me in computer labs without proper credentials while using the ```nice``` command to compile my music on supercomputers in California talking them into letting me turn off all of the terminals to prevent the fake login screen program(s) from potentially running, I'm like, "Aren't you even going to close the window?"

I was a good kid stopping terrorists and sex offenders while coding real time music software, my algorithm for compressing a Windows WAV file stolen from me by secretive Californians.

Comment: In music class at the University of Washington working on the UNIX NeXT systems built by a banished Apple founder, noted to be a robust operating system, I found I crashed it on a regular basis. One time I was trying to explain to the gal who couldn't hold the mouse right that it be best I use her computer for 2 minutes than make me use the server. She refused as did the grad student after I plead with them that it'd only take a minute otherwise, I might crash the server. I got my project sent off successfully. The server crashed for an hour or so. I tried to warn them like I always try to do.

Comment: I think the NeXT system crashed because I clicked the mouse between window changes and it didn't find a proper target. That was my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a folder called `torch` in the same directory which is being picked up.

The fix? `cd ..` (to change directory), and then start python and `import torch`, it should work.

Comment: Entering python and typing `import torch` raises an error in file `<stdin>` choking on ...\conda\envs\fastai-cpu\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py" line 76 in module 'from torch.C import *`

Comment: Do you have `VC Redist 2017`, `Numpy` and `intel-openmp` installed?

Comment: I'll get back to you when my new computer arrives with the supporting hardware. Apparently the Windows version REQUIRES a Nvidea GPU rather than faking it with CPU (or something like that). Either way, X-Mas is coming early this year.